# How to change tbar's text colour and style in extJS?

Tags: extjs4.1

I made a panel in extJS that has tbar. I want to change the colour and style of text of the items in the tbar. Specifically I would like "Report Manager"'s colour to be BLUE and it should be underlined.

```
function panelReports(){
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: {
        type: 'auto',
        align: 'left'
    },
    renderTo: document.body,
    tbar: [
    {
            enableToggle: true,
            text: 'Report Manager',
            scope   : this,
            handler : treeReportManager
    }]
});
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using the style config option in your tbar items?

Comment: @mindparse how to do that?.. Sorry, I am new to extJS..

Comment: @mindparse  I tried style config and it worked .. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me..

```
tbar: [
    {
            enableToggle: true,
            text: '<u> Report Manager </u>',
            style:{
                        color: 'blue'
                    } ,
            scope   : this,
            handler : treeReportManager
    }]
```